# Ffmpeg - youtube-dl

Tags: ffmpeg, youtube-dl, streams

I have try to use ffmpeg to download youtube media in mp3.

```
ffmpeg -i <url> -f mp3 output.mp3
```

It's working with other urls, but not with youtube-dl retrived youtube video urls. Ffmpeg returns error 403, forbidden. I can't download also with wget, but from browser and vnc player the url is working. I want to download separatly with ffmpeg, because I don't want to download in original format. Whats the problem? How can I fix it?

The commands:

```
./youtube-dl -f bestaudio -g https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=D-dONCnY_Yg

ffmpeg -i https://r1---sn-qxo7rn7e.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?signature=021CAFB9066554DD33675D89CC80D6E5FC616A7E.8A6222115FF91416C7F1B639B8F4A86671B40DD2&ipbits=0&sparams=clen%2Cdur%2Cei%2Cgir%2Cid%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Ckeepalive%2Clmt%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cpl%2Crequiressl%2Csource%2Cexpire&fvip=1&source=youtube&id=o-AALFu428zi6lOqHvA5xGfADpvNCR_BXItpMzqWb73CSH&mm=31%2C26&expire=1520111723&dur=293.721&lmt=1508989837160273&key=yt6&ip=35.227.125.114&ms=au%2Conr&ei=C7yaWuSpMYj5qQWY_qH4DQ&mv=m&mt=1520090001&requiressl=yes&gir=yes&mn=sn-qxo7rn7e%2Csn-cvb7ln7l&clen=4618202&keepalive=yes&c=WEB&mime=audio%2Fwebm&pl=24&itag=251&ratebypass=yes -f mp3 output.mp3
```

And ffmpeg returns error 403 forbidden.

Comment: Can't you use `youtube --format WHATEVER ...` to pick the format you want? Or the appropriate post-processing options?

Comment: I can't, because isn't mp3 format. I can use post-processing, but than I need to download before start the conversion. If I download with ffmpeg, I can start plaing in mp3, before the download is finished.

Comment: No, that's your failure. Just you can't understand the question.

Comment: @patrix He improved the question.

Comment: @edadam You can also use `youtube-dl -f bestaudio -x  --audio-format mp3 --audio-quality 0 [YOUTUBE_URL]` to download to mp3 directly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to quote the URL given to `ffmpeg` so the shell's consuming some of the characters as expressions or something else.

```bsh
ffmpeg -i "https://r1---sn-qxo7rn7e.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?signature=021CAFB9066554DD33675D89CC80D6E5FC616A7E.8A6222115FF91416C7F1B639B8F4A86671B40DD2&ipbits=0&sparams=clen%2Cdur%2Cei%2Cgir%2Cid%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Ckeepalive%2Clmt%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cpl%2Crequiressl%2Csource%2Cexpire&fvip=1&source=youtube&id=o-AALFu428zi6lOqHvA5xGfADpvNCR_BXItpMzqWb73CSH&mm=31%2C26&expire=1520111723&dur=293.721&lmt=1508989837160273&key=yt6&ip=35.227.125.114&ms=au%2Conr&ei=C7yaWuSpMYj5qQWY_qH4DQ&mv=m&mt=1520090001&requiressl=yes&gir=yes&mn=sn-qxo7rn7e%2Csn-cvb7ln7l&clen=4618202&keepalive=yes&c=WEB&mime=audio%2Fwebm&pl=24&itag=251&ratebypass=yes" output.mp3
```

Of course, this link has probably expired and you'll need to get a fresh one from `youtube-dl`.